# Checkbox value will not be changed when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a checkbox, which I styled with CSS, my problem is when i send the value of the checkbox to the controller using AJAX, the value stays as it was.

For example, my Checkbox-value was False (0) and then I clicked on the Checkbox, the Checkbox was set to True (1), then I sent the value to the controller using AJAX, but the controller still gets False (0).

```js
function success(data) {
    var rows;
    if (data != null) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {

            rows += "<tr>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<label class='checkbox-container' id ='checkbox-container'>" +
                item.Name +
                `<input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' id = 'myCheckbox' value='${item.IsActive}'                      ${item.IsActive  ? 'checked' : ''} />` +
                "<span class='checkmark'>" + "</span>" +
                "</label >" +
                "</td>"
        });
        $('#myTable tbody').append(rows);
    } else {

        alert("Something went wrong");
    }
}

function UpdateRefiInstituteById() {

    var checkboxValues = $('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();

 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Manage/UpdateRefiInstituteById',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
               IsActive: checkboxValues
        },
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

[image: Checkboxes]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('input[type="checkbox"].IsActive')`  is trying to select a checkbox with `class='IsActive'`. In your case, your checkbox has `class='myCheckbox'`.

Change the line to `$('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox')`.

### update

```
var checkboxValues = $('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox').map(function() {
        return $(this).prop('checked');
    }).toArray();
```

if you need 0 or 1 as unchecked and checked, simply do
`return $(this).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer !! I'm sorry my mistake, before I posted my code I changed the names because they were in German. Unfortunately I forgot to change it.


I mean, I get all values ​​in the controller, but unchangeable.

Comment: @Mr.R by unchangeable, you mean you got the correct value in your controller, but your checkboxes stays the same, right? For example, you uncheck a checkbox, and controller got 0 for false, but your UI still shows checked?  When you are appending new rows to your table, did you happen to forget to empty the old rows, and if you are printing the ```item.IsActive``` in your console, those are strings so your ```item.IsActive ? checked : ''``` will return checked

Comment: no, I mean the other way around.
my UI shows me that I have changed my checkbox from 0 to 1 and then I click on Submit and my controller gets the value 0, it should actually be 1.

Comment: @Mr.R  use props instead of value will work. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I used some data to help you see if its working. You can see that the checkbox values are correctly being mapped. This line is added:

```
${item.IsActive=='1' ? 'checked' : ''}
```

```js
function success() {
data = [
    {
        Name: "one",
        IsActive: "1"
    },
    {
        Name: "two",
        IsActive: "0"
    },
    {
        Name: "three",
        IsActive: "1"
    },
]
var rows;
if (data != null) {
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {

  rows += "<tr>" +
      "<td>" +
      "<label class='checkbox-container' id ='checkbox-container'>" +
      item.Name +
      `<input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' id = 'myCheckbox' value='${item.IsActive}' ${item.IsActive=='1' ? 'checked' : ''} />` +
      "<span class='checkmark'>" + "</span>" +
      "</label >" +
      "</td>"
  });
  $('#myTable tbody').append(rows);
  } else {
  alert("Something went wrong");
  }
}

function UpdateRefiInstituteById() {

  var checkboxValues = $('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
  }).toArray();

  console.log(checkboxValues);
}

success();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="UpdateRefiInstituteById()">Submit</button>
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, something is run with the variable `data` that you're passing in `success()` function or, problem in `/Manage/UpdateRefiInstituteById` page

Comment: Thanks! and yes, you are absolutely right, the problem is in the **success()**, but I cannot find out the problem -:

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the checkbox you created on the `success()` function. The checkboxes you created in the `success()` function has class `myCheckbox` and you're trying to pass checkboxes values of `IsActive`  class in `UpdateRefiInstituteById()` function via ajax.

You should change

```
var checkboxValues = $('input[type="checkbox"].IsActive').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

to

```
var checkboxValues = $('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

Also, you have functions inside functions. You need to take those out

Comment: Many thanks for your response. You are right that there was a mistake, it was because I wrote in German earlier, and then I translated into English so that people could understand it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help! my controller gets all values ​​from the checkboxes but unchangeable

Comment: this is my controller : `[HttpPost]`
       `public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRefiInstituteById( bool[] isActive)
        {`